# Удаление мест из заказа в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Вся функция:

```
function evpl_get_order_table_admin($order_id) {
    $order = evpl_get_order($order_id);
    if (!$order) return false;
    $tablePlaces = array();
    foreach ($order->order_places as $place) {
        $tablePlaces[$place->event_id][mysql2date('d.m.Y', $place->event_date) ][mysql2date('H:i', $place->event_date) ] = $place->event_places;
    }
    $content = '<table bordercolor="сссссс" border="1" cellpadding="5" class="evpl-order-details">';
    foreach ($tablePlaces as $event_id => $event_dates) {
        $room_id = get_post_meta($event_id, 'event-room', 1);
        $room = evpl_get_room($room_id);
        //print_r ($event_room);
    
        // Вывожу массив с местами:
        $order_details_mest = $order->order_places;
        $result_mest = json_decode(json_encode($order_details_mest), true);        
        $result_mests = $result_mest['0']['event_places'];

        echo '<br><pre>', print_r( $result_mests ), '</pre><br>';

        foreach ($event_dates as $date => $event_times) {
            foreach ($event_times as $time => $places) {
                if (!$places) continue;
                // Город
                $terms = get_the_terms($event_id, 'event-type');
                $city = $terms[0]->name;
                // ДК
                $event_room = get_post_meta($event_id);
                $content.= '<tr>' . '<th colspan="7">' . $city . ' в ' . $event_room['home_dk'][0] . '</th>' . '</tr>';
                $content.= '<tr>' . '<td colspan="5">' . get_the_title($event_id) . '</th>' . '<td colspan="2">' . $date . ' ' . $time . '</th>' . '</tr>';
                $content.= '<tr>' . '<th>№</th>' . '<th>Сектор</th>' . '<th>Местo</th>' . '<th>Ряд</th>' . '<th>Стоимость билета</th>' . '<th>Сервисный сбор</th>' .  '</tr>';
                $a = 0;
                foreach ($places as $place) {

                    $a++;
                    $percent = get_post_meta($event_id, 'collection', 1);
                    if ($percent != 0) $percent = $place['p'] * $percent / 100;

                    $content.= '<tr class="evpl-cart-place">' . '<td>' . $a . '</td>' . '<td>' . $place['t'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $place['n'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $place['r'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $place['p'] . ' рублей</td>' . '<td>' . $percent . ' рублей </td>' . '<td> <a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=evpl-orders&action=order-details&order_id='.$order_id.'&del='. $place['n'] .'">delete</a> </td>' . '</tr>';

                    if (isset($_POST['del'])) {
                        global $wpdb;

                        $mest_del = $_POST['del'];

                        $wpdb->delete( 
                            'wp_12ae_evpl_orders_places',                      
                            array( 'order_id' => $order_id, 'event_places' => "$number" ) 
                        );

                        header('Location: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=evpl-orders&action=order-details&order_id='.$order_id.'');
                        exit;
                    }
                  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Массив мест:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [p] => 1000
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 9:13
            [r] => 9
            [n] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [p] => 1000
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 9:12
            [r] => 9
            [n] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [p] => 1000
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 9:11
            [r] => 9
            [n] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [p] => 1000
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 9:3
            [r] => 9
            [n] => 14
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [p] => 1000
            [t] => Партер
            [i] => 9:4
            [r] => 9
            [n] => 13
        )

)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать запрос на удаление каждого места по отдельности? По его номеру `$place['n']`
У меня не получается выполнить запрос, так как не совсем понимаю как разложить правильно массив и удалить мне нужные данные из него.